# numpyのndarrayの指定した複数の行を取り除く方法

Tags: python, python3, numpy

値が昇順にソートされたリスト`A`とMかけるN行の`numpy.ndarray`型の行列`M`があります。
この`M`から`A`にある数字に対応する行を削除したいです。
例として、5かける3の行列から2行目と4行目を削除する場合を考えます。

```
import numpy as np
A = [2, 4]
B = np.array(
[[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9],
[10, 11, 12],
[13, 14, 15]]
)

# new_array  =
```

`new_arrray`をこの例の期待する出力とした時、中身は

```
[[1, 2, 3],
[7, 8, 9],
[13, 14, 15]]
```

となるような方法を教えてください。

Comment: `np.delete(B, np.array(A)-1, axis=0)` な方法も。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[numpy.delete](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html)で特定の行を削除できます。

[NumPyで任意の行・列を削除するnp.deleteの使い方](https://note.nkmk.me/python-numpy-delete/)
[SO本家の類似回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47622289)

```
import numpy as np
A = [2, 4]
B = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9],
              [10, 11, 12],
              [13, 14, 15]])
A = [i - 1 for i in A]   # 0始まりの行番号を削除するのでAから1を減じた配列を渡す
B = np.delete(B, A, axis=0)
print(B)
```

Answer (score 0):

NumPyの[Boolean配列によるIndexing機能](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#indexing-with-boolean-arrays)を利用した別解です。

```py
import numpy as np
A = [2, 4]
B = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9],
              [10, 11, 12],
              [13, 14, 15]])

# Bからの行選択用フィルタ配列を用意
selector = np.ones(len(B), dtype=bool)
selector[np.array(A) - 1] = False
# array([ True, False,  True, False,  True])

print(B[selector])
# array([[ 1,  2,  3],
#        [ 7,  8,  9],
#        [13, 14, 15]])
```